# Not able to use alias across tests in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to create a framework for API tests using cypress and I am facing an issue accessing the data between tests using an alias. Is there something that I am missing?

custom.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getResource', function (uri) {
    cy.request({
        url: uri,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        return cy.wrap(response);
    });
});
```

test.js

```
exports.__esModule = true;
context('requests', function () {
    it('validate get call response', function () {
        let re = cy.getResource('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2','resp')
        re.then(function (response) {
            cy.wrap(response.body).as('respbody');
            cy.wrap(response.status).as('respstatus');
            //cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        });
    });
    it('Tests test', function () {
            cy.wait('@respbody').then((body) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
            });
            
    });
});
```

[image]

cypress version - 8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design cypress cleans up aliases after each test. So you can do something like this [cypress recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/db2f5a9c2e3dcf3b4f2b352f10a2d6ed443946fe/examples/fundamentals__fixtures/cypress/integration/load-fixtures-spec.js#L103)

Your `getResource` custom command is taking just one parameter, hence we are passing just one papameter.

```
exports.__esModule = true;
let responseBody;
let responseStatus;
context('requests', () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.getResource('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
            .then(function(response) {
                responseBody = response.body
                responseStatus = response.status
            })
    })
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.wrap(responseBody).as('responseBody')
        cy.wrap(responseStatus).as('responseStatus')
    })
    it('Get Response status', function() {
        cy.wait('@responseStatus').then((responseStatus) => {
            console.log(responseStatus)
        })
    })
    it('Get Response Body', function() {
        cy.wait('@responseBody').then((responseBody) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseBody))
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this worked for me. Just letting you know, looks like the cy.wait is only for routes, so changed it to get, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad that you were able to figure it out.

Comment: what happens if the cucumber is used, is the alias carried over steps?